# Redirect all older URL ending with .aspx to some URL

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I have upgraded a website to a newer mvc version of asp.net. Its already done, however I'm not sure how to redirect older page request ending with aspx to a new URL.

How can I redirect all page requests ending with .aspx to home page URL like www.somedomain.com/

I would like to use rewrite module.

Comment: Well - routing is not a simple thing to just explain/do for you, so - what have you done so far and what code can you show? Also take a look here for some introduction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: Do you want to redirect every request to let's say http://www.somedomain.com/Users.aspx to http://www.somedomain.com/Users or to http://www.somedomain.com/?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For using the rewrite module to redirect everything with an aspx ending to an extension less URL you'll have to first install the URL rewrite module. Best is to install the URL rewrite module with [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)

Once installed add the following section to your <system.webServer> section in web.config:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to extensionless URL" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*.aspx" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This section defines that any URL matching the pattern *.aspx will be redirected (302) to the extension less URL equivalent. For example a request to `/Users.aspx` would be redirected to `/Users`.

In case you would want to redirect all .aspx URLs to some domain you would change the action to this:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.somedomain.com" redirectType="Found" />
```

A 302 redirect is not ideal from a SEO perspective, so I would recommend to **test** with a 302 redirect and in case everything works as desired switch to a permanent redirect by using the action:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
```